# Load <link> tags async with guaranteed order

Tags: html, css, asynchronous

After running [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed), recommended that I use `async` or `defer` for my CSS content

> **Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content**
>
> Your page has 6 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
>
> None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.

So I am exploring the `async` attribute on the `<link>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset "css/bootstrap.min.css"}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset "css/font-awesome.min.css"}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset "css/screen.css"}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset "css/highlight_styles/rainbow.css"}}">
```

Now if I add a `async` attribute to the above `<link>` tags, I am worried that the CSS will not load in order. **Since [css order does matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231614/does-the-order-of-css-stylesheet-definitions-matter) and order can not be guaranteed with `async` what are the other options?**

Options I have considered:

- Using the `defer` attribute guarantees the order, but it doesn't seem to be supported for the [`<link>` Tag Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#link-type-import)
- To `cat` all my css together that way I can guarantee the order. However I was wondering if there was a way around this with multiple `async` `<link>` tags, as this would be a pain to do every time even with gulp/grunt.
- I could probably write some fancy javascript to do this, but that just seems like overkill. (JS -> CSS -> JS would probably reduce any time saved).

---

**Some references:**

According to [webkit](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1395/running-scripts-in-webkit/) order seems to be preserved for `defer` but not for `async`:

> Both async and defer scripts begin to download immediately without pausing the parser and both support an optional onload handler to address the common need to perform initialization which depends on the script. The difference between async and defer centers around when the script is executed. Each async script executes at the first opportunity after it is finished downloading and before the window’s load event. This means it’s possible (and likely) that async scripts are not executed in the order in which they occur in the page. The defer scripts, on the other hand, are guaranteed to be executed in the order they occur in the page. That execution starts after parsing is completely finished, but before the document’s DOMContentLoaded event.

CSS Order Matters: [Does the order of css stylesheet definitions matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231614/does-the-order-of-css-stylesheet-definitions-matter)

W3C Documentation: [`<link>` Tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#link-type-import) only supports `async` and no mention of `defer`

Comment: Are you sure the order they are loaded matters? Or is it only the order they are listed that matters?

Comment: @pstenstrm I believe `screen.css` overwrites some bootstrap elements. So if `sceen.css` loaded first, then `bootstrap.css`, bootstrap would overwrite  screen.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. They could load in any order and still display properly if the browser uses the order they appear in the page. Just because they load in a different order doesn't mean they won't be rendered properly once they have all loaded.

Comment: Ohh I see what you are saying... I don't know, the docs for async link tags are almost non existent. The docs for async script state that `async script executes at the first opportunity after it is finished downloading`. Order of CSS is based on execution, right?

Comment: concatinate all your css in to 1 file, there you can specify the order, and only 1 file is downloaded, even better if you would minimize the file.

Comment: Either it is asynchronously or with guaranteed order! When there is a guaranteed order it is synchronous.

Comment: @joao_pimentel I don't think you understand what part I want asynchronous, I don't want the browser to be blocked loading other files. I want the webpage to load first, then load my css. Load content categories (css, js) asynchronously, but load within those categories synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

After further research it seems that a few of my assumptions were incorrect.

The [link tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#link-type-import) with `type="import"` can be async, but not the `type="text/css"`

The best alterantive I could find is to use a library called [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS), below is an example of how it is used:

```
<head>
    <script src="loadCSS.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // load a file
        loadCSS("Styles-V6.min.css");
    </script>
</head>
```